# Правильное использование сервисов и контроллеров Java/Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Такой вопрос:
В моем контроллере используется множество сервисов. Допустим, мне надо изменить поля в Book, User и Review после получения запроса в ReviewController. Тогда мой конструктор выглядит так:

```
@Autowired
public ReviewController(ReviewService reviewService, BookService bookService, UserService userService) {
    this.reviewService = reviewService;
    this.bookService = bookService;
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

И мой метод контроллера:

```
 @PostMapping("/{id}")
public String createReview(@PathVariable Integer id, @ModelAttribute Review review){
    review.setUser(userService.loadUserByUsername(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication().getName()).user());
    review.setBook(bookService.findOne(id).get());
    reviewService.save(review);

    Book reviewedBook = bookService.findOne(id).get();
    List<Review> reviews = reviewedBook.getReviews();
    reviews.add(review);
    reviewedBook.setReviews(reviews);

    User user = userService.loadUserByUsername(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()).user();
    List<Review> usersReviews = user.getReviews();
    usersReviews.add(review);
    user.setReviews(usersReviews);
    return "redirect:/books";
}
```

Насколько это плохая практика? И если да, то как это можно исправить? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вот это всё бы из контроллера - в "общий" сервис, да в транзакцию, да убрать двойное получение юзера...

Comment: У вас не вызываются методы `save` для сервисов `bookService` / `userService`

Comment: @kami т.е. как я понимаю, мне нужно создать что то наподобие ReviewBookUserService, и там делать это всё? И что я должен в нем использовать, сторонние сервисы, или репозитории?

Comment: `что то наподобие ReviewBookUserService, и там делать это всё? И что я должен в нем использовать, сторонние сервисы, или репозитории?` - да. И лучше сервисы, чтобы конкретные функциональные блоки не отличались реализацией при вызове из общего и при вызове частных сервисов.